# Difference between relative=up, relative=parent, and relative=top in selenium selectFrame

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, frames

What are the differences between

```
 Selenium.SelectFrame("relative=up");
 Selenium.SelectFrame("relative=top");
 Selenium.SelectFrame("relative=parent");
```

Could anyone give me an explanation using examples? I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, it seems that `relative=up` and `relative=parent` are the same thing, and simply goes one level up from the currently-selected frame; that is, it selects the frame which directly contains the currently-selected frame.

`relative=top` seems to select the top frame; that is, the root frame, the frame with no parents, the frame of which all the other frames are descendents.

So, use `Selenium.SelectFrame("relative=up")` or `Selenium.SelectFrame("relative=parent")` when you would like to go "up" one level, and use `Selenium.SelectFrame("relative=top")` when you would like to go up to the main frame, as in the original window/frame whose url is in the browser's address bar.